# How much information is in the question "How much information is in this question?"?

Tags: computability, information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

I'm actually not sure where to pose this question, but we do have an Information Theory tag so this must be the place. The "simple" question is in the title: how do I know how many bits of information is in the question: "How much information is in this question?"?

Or, for a simpler one, how many bits of information is in the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"?

To clarify, I'm *not* asking how much information is in it when read by someone, but rather how much information, in bits, does it have inherently? Intuitively, there should be an answer.

I was going over my old papers and stumbled about one where I attempted to measure how effective mnemonics are using information theory. I didn't get very far, but now the question's in my head again. Any links to other articles or journals would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I prefer this question: How much information is in the question "How much information is in this question?"?

Comment: That's a good edit, I'll change my question now

Comment: But now it's not a Quine!  "contains how much information?" contains how much information? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in fact an existing mathematical definition of this exact concept called [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), but you will surely be disappointed because there is a serious catch: it is only defined up to a constant additive factor which depends on your model of computation.  But aside from that factor, it is an invariant metric across a wide range of models, so even though we can't pin down the "inherent" Kolmogorov complexity of a particular string without reference to a particular model, if we have two infinite sequences of strings, we can compare them to see if one [eventually becomes more complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin-Loef_random) than the other in a more broadly-applicable sense.

Comment: I'm trying to research the topic now, but to give me some ground to stand on, if it's just a simple model, what model of computation could be applicable for my question? :)

Comment: Whatever you are most comfortable with, since the difference is bounded by a constant.  In C you might write main(){printf("How much information is in this question?");} which is longer than the output but on a Turing machine with output mapped in an appropriate way (bitstrings to ASCII for example) there might be a more clever solution that exploits the redundancy (6 occurrences of "i" for example).  The difference is bounded by a constant because each model can emulate the other.